# Why don't we include import lines in our answers?

Tags: discussion

When I first started coding about 3 years ago, I was infinitely frustrated by "crappy" answers in 250 rep posts due to the fact that the n00b in me didn't realize that you needed import lines.

Eg.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

I've had a bunch of discussion about this, and everyone says that I'm a sissy for wishing that people included import lines in their answers. What's wrong with it? Why do I get so much hate for requesting something that would take a few flicks of a track pad to get for the person answering, but could potentially cause half an hour of frustration on the asker's part? Whenever I answer questions, or whenever I see an answer that I can edit to include import lines, I try to do so.

It seems like common courtesy to me. It's like someone hands you a box with the answer in it, and the import line is the key to making it work, and they don't give you that for seemingly no reason. Is it just me, or does this get under anyone else's skin?

Comment: It's the same in C. Unless asked for a specific function, I try to include all necessary `#include`s just to prevent the unavoidable follow-up comment "ur code dont work!!" Also recommended for single functions where you need to use an include not used in the original code.

Comment: I agree that including the imports generally makes for a nicer answer, one that is more readily usable by people who might not be familiar with the technologies involved. (And sometimes it is crucial because there exist multiple alternatives from where a class/function/what-have-you could be imported.) I'm not seeing though what concrete outcome you're hoping for by asking this on Meta. People have different opinions as to what answers should contain. What's new?

Comment: If you're blindly copy + pasting answers without understanding how they work at all (imports are somewhat a 'fundamental' thing to figure out), you're going to run into a wall *somewhere*. Let's not pollute good posts with boilerplate just to cater to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: *I'm not seeing though what concrete outcome you're hoping for by asking this on Meta.*  @Louis - I think the OP's real question is in the 2nd paragraph, *What's wrong with it?* They kind of already answered their "Is it just me" when they said that everyone disagrees with them. I think they're hoping for a reason they can at least understand, even if they don't agree with it.

Comment: If you don't know about this already, then what you need is a book or tutorial, not Stack Overflow. You're expected to know the basics already *unless you're specifically asking about them*. More generally, **you are expected to be competent enough to understand the answers that you are given**. If that is not the case, you need to search elsewhere or ask a different question.

Answer (score 11):

Because most boilerplate headers/include/imports/etc. are quite long and irrelevant. Answerers try to be succinct and to the point. Including 10-15 lines of irrelevant code can be distracting.

Comment: If you've got that many imports, it's likely that the code in the answer is longer than it needs to be anyway. While sometimes I post snippets, I frequently post short but complete examples that can be copied/pasted/compiled/run in answers - and I rarely need more than 3 or 4 lines to do that.

Comment: That's because imports in C# are very dense in terms of the number of classes that they bring in. You can import, for example, `System.Collections.Generic` and get pretty much everything you need. That isn't the case in every language. For a simple algorithmic solution in C++, you'd end up having includes for a bunch of different standard library headers, which is not useful.